# Как работать в цикле с более чем 1 горутиной?

Tags: golang, async-await

Есть входные данные, кол-во потоков и кол-во профилей.
Каждая подписка увеличивает profile на 1, пока он не достигнет totalProfile

Все это должно выполняться параллельно в определенном кол-ве потоков Threads

Сейчас каждый поток проходится по всему списку и в конце падает "panic: sync: negative WaitGroup counter"

```
func Sub(threads, totalProfiles int) {

var wg sync.WaitGroup
var mu sync.Mutex
var profile = 1
wg.Add(profile)

start := time.Now()

for k := 1; k < threads; k++ {

    go func(k int) {
        for i := profile; profile < totalProfiles; i++ {
            fmt.Printf("Thread %v: profile %v done\n", k, i)
            mu.Lock()
            profile++
            mu.Unlock()
        }
        defer wg.Done()
    }(k)
}
wg.Wait()
fmt.Println(time.Now().Sub(start).Seconds())
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```go
func Sub(threads, totalProfiles int) {

    wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
    wg.Add(threads)

    // очередь задач
    tasks := make(chan int)

    // запуск пула воркеров,  обрабатывающих задачи
    for k := 0; k < threads; k++ {
        // воркер в виде анонимной функции
        go func(k int) {
            defer wg.Done() // место для defer
            // воркер будет обрабатывать задачи из очереди пока очередь задач не закроется
            for task := range tasks {
                fmt.Printf("Thread %d: profile %d done\n", k, task)
            }
        }(k)
    }

    // передача задач в очередь
    for i := 0; i < totalProfiles; i++ {
        tasks <- i
    }
    // закрываем канал после того, как все задачи в него переданы
    close(tasks)

    // ждем пока все воркеры завершат работу
    wg.Wait()
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/5jJMraStA4k

Answer (score 0):

Потому что вы делаете добавление записи в WaitGroup только один раз.
А нужно каждый раз перед тем как запускаете горутину. Т.е. `wg.Add(profile)` нужно перенести внутри цикла **for** - но перед вызовом **go**

И нужно использовать `wg.Add(1)` - переменная тут лишняя. Вернее даже вредная.

А так вызов `wg.Add(1)` увеличивает счетчик на 1. Вызов `wg.Done()` уменьшает счетчик на 1.

UPD: по вопросам в комментариях

Самый простой вариант это наверное что-то такое

```
func Sub(threads, totalProfiles int) {

var wg sync.WaitGroup
var mu sync.Mutex

start := time.Now()
chunksize = totalProfiles / threads

for k := 0; k < threads; k++ {
    wg.Add(1)
    go func(s, e int) {
        for i := s; i < e; i++ {
            fmt.Printf("Thread %v: profile %v done\n", k, i)
        }
        defer wg.Done()
    }(k * chunksize, (k+1)*chunksize)
}
wg.Wait()
fmt.Println(time.Now().Sub(start).Seconds())
}
```

Т.е. весь список профилей разбиваем на равные куски. И для каждого куска запускаем отдельную горутину. Писал так сказать "на коленке" так что могут быт ькакие-то неточности по синтаксису или же логике. Но думаю что основная идея понятна.

Comment: Смысл в том чтобы, допустим 10 потоков обрабатывали 1000 профилей одновременно.
Попробовал сделать что Вы сказали, такая же проблема, повторяются данные и потоки работают поочередно

Comment: Для того чтобы  10 потоков обрабатывали 1000 профилей - это надо еще дополнительно организовывать очередь или же формировать какой-то пул задач. В вашей же реализации сейчас получается что запускается несколько потоков и каждый этот поток делает одну и ту же работу.

Comment: Подскажите как организовать очередь? И в целом какой способ более оптимальный для этой задачи

Comment: @hey отредактировал ответ

Comment: "нужно каждый раз перед тем как запускаете горутину" - это неправильно заключение. можно добавить один раз где угодно до wg.Wait()